# Go build error: no non-test Go files in <dir>

Tags: go, build, compiler-errors

Getting an error when trying to run `go build ./...` from my $GOPATH/src .

```
no non-test Go files in <dir>
```

The error is correct there are no test files in `<dir>` but why is that causing a compile error? Is it a bug?

Comment: The error says there are no `non-test` files. There's nothing to build in that directory.

Comment: "from my $GOPATH/src" that doesn't sound right - that builds **everything** - what are you trying to build?

Comment: @fstanis _everything_

Comment: You are aware that `go build ./...` doesn't _do_ anything, other than building things and throwing away the results, right?

Comment: @JimB `go install ./...` exits with the same error

Comment: That command makes a little more sense, but running it on all of `GOPATH/src` is still questionable. Just like the error says, there's a directory with no non-test files, and you're instructing the go tool to build something out of it. The only thing you can do with that package is run `go test`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling it a bug… the build shouldn't fail if the tests compile. Filed here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22409

The bug I filed was a duplicate of https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8279 looks like it was broken in 1.3.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a bug, unless you see somewhere in the docs that contradicts this behaviour you should probably close the issue you've created.

Tests in go normally live in the package they are testing. You have made a new package with package main at the top (invalid if you also have main elsewhere), and then have included no go source files in that tests/main package (invalid as package has no go source files apart from tests, which the compiler complains about explicitly).

Possible solutions for you (assuming this isn't just a hypothetical question):

- Move tests for main to test_main.go (this is what readers will
  expect)
- Add doc.go file to your tests pkg and call it package tests in
  both files

The reason for putting tests in the same package is to ensure they have access to the entire package, if you want to split them to another package you'll find you have to test as an external user of the pkg - this may be painful. Main is also a special case as well as you don't normally import it.

Comment: That issue is closed with won’t fix

Answer (score 1):

First, check your $GOPATH has been set correctly. Learn more at [here](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SettingGOPATH).

Then, check if any '_' in your file name. Remove these '_'s and try again. 
;-)