# Testing generated Go code without co-locating tests

Tags: unit-testing, go, code-coverage

Have some auto-generated golang code for protobuf messages and I'm looking to add some additional testing, without locating the file under the same directory path. This is to allow easy removal of the existing generated code to be sure that if a file is dropped from being generated, it's not left included in the codebase by accident.

The current layout of these files are controlled by prototool so I have something like the following:

```
/pkg/<other1>
/pkg/<other2>
/pkg/<name-generated>/v1/component_api.pb.go
/pkg/<name-generated>/v1/component_api.pb.gw.go
/pkg/<name-generated>/v1/component_api.pb.validate.go
```

The `*.validate.go` comes from envoyproxy/protoc-gen-validate, and `*.pb.go` & `*.pb.gw.go` are coming from protobuf and grpc libraries. The `other1` and `other2` are two helper libraries that we have included along with the generated code to make it easier for client side apps. The server side is in a separate repo and imports as needed.

Because it's useful to be able to delete `/pkg/<name>` before re-running prototool I've placed some tests of component_api (mostly to exercise the validate rules generated automatically) under the path:

```
/internal/pkg/<name>/v1/component_api_test.go
```

While this works for `go test -v ./...`, it appears not to work to well when generating coverage with `-coverpkg`.

```
go test -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile=coverage/go/coverage.out -v ./...

go build <pkgname>/internal/pkg/<name>/v1: no non-test Go files in ....
<output from the tests in /internal/pkg/<name>/v1/component_api_test.go>
....
....
coverage: 10.5% of statements in ./...
ok      <pkgname>/internal/pkg/<name>/v1    0.014s  coverage: 10.5% of statements in ./...
FAIL    <pkgname>/pkg/other1 [build failed]
FAIL    <pkgname>/pkg/other2 [build failed]
?       <pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1 [no test files]
FAIL
Coverage tests failed
Generated coverage/go/html/main.html
```

The reason for use of `-coverpkg` is that without it there doesn't seem to be anything spotting that any of the code under `<pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1` is covered, and we've see issues with what it reports previously not showing the real level of coverage, which are solved by use of `-coverpkg`:

```
go test -cover -coverprofile=coverage/go/coverage.out ./...
ok      <pkgname>internal/pkg/<name>/v1 0.007s  coverage: [no statements]
ok      <pkgname>/pkg/other1 0.005s coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      <pkgname>/pkg/other2    0.177s  coverage: 100.0% of statements
?       <pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1 [no test files]
```

Looking at the resulting coverage/go/coverage.out includes no mention of anything under `<pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1` being exercised.

I'm not attached to the current layout beyond being limited on `<pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1` being automatically managed by prototool and it's rules around naming for the generated files. Would like to ensure the other modules we have can remain exported to be used as helper libraries and I would like to be able to add tests for `<pkgname>/pkg/<name>/v1` without needing to locate them in the same directory to allow for easy delete + recreate of generated files, while still getting sensible coverage reports.

I've tried fiddling with the packages passed to `-coverpkg` and replacing `./...` on the command-line and haven't been able to come up with something that works. Perhaps I'm just not familiar with the right invocation?

Other than that is there a different layout that will take care of this for me?

Answer (score 3):

To handle this scenario, simply create a doc.go file in the same directory as the dis-located tests with just the package and comment. This will allow the standard arguments to work and golang appears to be reasonably happy with an empty file.

Once in place the following will work as expected.

```
go test -coverpkg=./... -coverprofile=coverage/go/coverage.out -v ./...
```

Idea based on suggestion in https://stackoverflow.com/a/47025370/1597808